# Laravel Cashier and creating customer and card in Stripe

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-5.1, laravel-cashier

How can I create a customer and card by using Laravel `Cashier` library so that I can charge it later? No I am not looking for subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Laravel 5, the following will work. For the stripe gateway there is a `createStripeCustomer` function. You can manually call that function to request a stripe_token for the new customer and store it.

```
//pass the user object to the gateway; it must implement BillableContract
$gateway = new \Laravel\Cashier\StripeGateway($user);

//manually create a new Customer instance with Stripe
$customer = $gateway->createStripeCustomer($request->get('stripe_token'));

//update the model's info
$gateway->updateLocalStripeData($customer);
```

You can then use this customer token for future subscriptions, etc.

Comment: But I am rather want to use Stripe's SDK instead of `Cashier` now.